# EventEmmiter in service is not emitting

Tags: angular

Since the service constructor hitting before the component, `crmService.actualName.subscribe()` will not happen till the next time I emit.
Is there any way to emit right when a new subscription is joining? this way I can "reply" back with the current value...
Some thing like:

```
this.actualName.onSubscribe(x => emit(x));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ns7j2n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root"})
export class CrmService {
  public actualName : EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(){
    this.actualName.emit("Angular 6 is the actual name")
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular'; 
  constructor(private crmService : CrmService){
    crmService.actualName.subscribe(name => {
      this.name = name;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `EventEmitter`. Change your service code to following:

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root"})
export class CrmService {
  public actualName : BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
  constructor(){
    this.actualName.next("Angular 6 is the actual name")
  }
}
```

Link to [**working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tf9t1m?file=src/app/app.component.ts).